# Why C# Application does not create file while running from windows task scheduler?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a C# desktop application which should create and write into a text file while running. And this application suppose to run every morning 9:00 so, I have created a task in the windows task scheduler to run this program. While running from the windows task scheduler the application is working fine except creating any text file. But if I close the application and re-run by double click then it creates text file accordingly.

Here is my text file writing code:

```
 public void process_log(string str, string logtype)
    { 

        try
        {
            string myFile = null;
            string myDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            string myDir = null;
            switch (logtype)
            {
                case "process":
                    myDir = "logs\\process\\";
                    break;
                case "err":
                    myDir = "logs\\err\\";
                    break;
                case "URLSTR":
                    myDir = "logs\\URLSTR\\";
                    break;
                case "MOMT":
                    myDir = "logs\\MOMT\\";
                    break;
                default:
                    myDir = "logs\\";
                    break;
            }

            myFile = myDir + myDate + ".txt";


            StreamWriter sw = default(StreamWriter);
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(myDir);
            if (dir.Exists == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(myDir);
            }

            if (File.Exists(myFile))
            {
                sw = File.AppendText(myFile);
            }
            else
            {
                sw = File.CreateText(myFile);
            }
            sw.WriteLine(str);
            sw.Close();



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            str = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ex.Message;
            process_log(str, "err");
            str = ex.StackTrace;
            process_log(str, "err");


        }

    }
```

This issue is getting very serious as we can't find any log file for everyday.
Please help on this, Thanks.

Comment: I'd check permissions and try using absolute paths.

Comment: Log every step including the exception(s) to the EventViewer for now and see if you get anything there.

Comment: have you figured this out? I am having the same problem even I have given full permission to everyone?

Comment: Yes, I had to add the complete path for the textfile location and now it is working good.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is a permissions isssue. When you run the application by double-clicking it runs in your user context. When Windows Schedulers runs it it runs under the context specificed in the task definition page in the Windows Scheduler, defaulting to Local System (I think). You may check this by changing the execution context in the Windows Scheduler task definition page and run it as your own account - it should then work.

Answer (score 5):

I have solved my problem by referring the complete path of the textfile location to be created. For example: "C:\MyLog\logs\URLSTR\" and after that it is working fine. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time this seem like a permission issues, as the scheduler executor does not have the right to create the file on particular location.

Option:

- grant the permission to the executor.
- change to other executor that has permission to execute the job.

To verify, check the history of the job see if any error message there.